# Server Side Validations in asp.net bootstrap on client side

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, client-side-validation, server-side-validation

I have used Bootstrap for my asp.net web form client side validations.

How can I achieve Server side validations.

Please give me suggestions on this.

Regards,

Venkata Avula.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for validation like username ,email name checking from server side .better use following link for reference

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20abe2/how-to-check-user-name-or-email-availability-using-Asp-Net/ry

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-check-username-availability.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.
As I mentioned earlier, I am using bootstrap to do form validations on client side. Like checking empty, email and length etc. 

Ex: if first name is empty.. bootstrap will show you error message and hightlights the textbox with red color. 

So, I would like to achieve same thing with the server side validations if any validations missed on the client side. 

I hope it is clear if not please ask me more.